# Nested Tree (or XML) to datatable

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a nested XML file like this

```
<students>
    <student id=1>
        <course cid=1 name="cse" />
        <course cid=2 name="eee" />
        <course cid=3 name="mech" />
        <course cid=4 name="it" />
    </studnet>
    <student id=2>
        <course cid=1 name="cse" />
        <course cid=2 name="eee" />
        <course cid=3 name="mech" />
        <course cid=4 name="it" />
    </studnet>
```

I want to save it in datatable in this format

```
id    cid    name
1     1      cse
1     2      ece
1     3      mech
1     4      it
2     1      cse
2     2      eee
2     3      mech
2     4      it
```

Currently I am parsing the XML file and strong it in a tree datastructure

```
class Node{
    string Text;
    List<Attribute> Attributes;
    List<Node> Children;
}
class Attribute{
    string name;
    string value;
}
```

I can parse the XML and store it in any Data structure. The XML file can have any format and attributes, thats why I have used Children of Type Attribute and not defined the specific property(id, cis etc) for the class.

Any idea how I can convert my tree created from XML to datatable. I plan to bind this datarable and bind it to datagrid and again save it into XML.

Comment: You can bind XML directly to datagrid using `XmlDataProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

To bind XML to datatable you can use this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.ReadXml();
```

Comment: How `XML` data will be read automatically using `dt.ReadXml();`?

Comment: Hi, the ReadXML method have 4 overloads you can use any of them to load the XML file to Datatable

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of these simple examples, they Serialize a class to and from XML. this example returns a List which can the be used a DataSource of the DataGrid

http://nakdev.somee.com/#1&C54B782F02A748E0BCCDFE50B0586BA2&cs

And this example demonstrates setting the DataSource of the DataGrid to a DataSet

http://nakdev.somee.com/#2&1BC37606DFD843EC94249A93B4BD17A2&cs